# onbeforeprint() and onafterprint() equivalent for non IE browsers

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, onbeforeprint

I want to send some info back to my database when a user prints a certain web page.  I can do this in IE with `onbeforeprint()` and `onafterprint()` but I would like to browser agnostic way of doing the same thing.  Don't care which combination of technologies I have to use (PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, HTML) so long as it gets done.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Still having some problems with this.  I tried the putting my function in my `Print.css` as an image, but I am messing it up some how.  Then I tried just adding a event listener, but I cannot get that to work quite right either.  If anyone can provide some more details on how I might call a function right before print in ANY browser I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

I am giving up on this for now, I have settled with another way of doing what I want. I look forward to the day when FireFox supports onbeforeprint() and onafterprint().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I m not [sure other browsers will allow you to](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307258). You could of course specify an image somewhere in a print stylesheet, which probably only will be called on a print, for the `onbeforeprint`

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this?

http://www.siteexperts.com/forums/viewConverse.asp?d_id=19568

Comment: Don't know if that'll work. I would suggest calling a server-sided script as the image source which indeed returns an image, and just does the stuff you like (log a print action, possibly set a session variable other js on the page can retrieve / poll for etc.)

Comment: onbeforeprint is supported by Firefox since version 6, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeprint

Answer (score 34):

[Many browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) now support [`window.matchMedia`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-window-matchmedia). This API allows you to detect when CSS media queries go into effect (e.g., rotating the screen or printing the document). For a cross-browser approach, combine `window.matchMedia` with `window.onbeforeprint`/`window.onafterprint`.

*The following may result in multiple calls to `beforePrint()` and `afterPrint()` (for example, [Chrome fires the listener every time the print preview is regenerated](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85013)). This may or may not be desirable depending on the particular processing you're doing in response to the print.*

```
if ('matchMedia' in window) {
    // Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10 support mediaMatch listeners
    window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function(media) {
        if (media.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            // Fires immediately, so wait for the first mouse movement
            $(document).one('mouseover', afterPrint);
        }
    });
} else {
    // IE and Firefox fire before/after events
    $(window).on('beforeprint', beforePrint);
    $(window).on('afterprint', afterPrint);
}
```

More: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

Comment: Worth noting that Chrome seems to fire the print event twice.

Comment: ...actually four times -- once with media.matches=true, then media.matches=false, then media.matches=true, then media.matches=false.

Comment: This does not work when I use "Print using system dialog" in Chrome. The window closes but the printing fails. Just reporting. :)

Comment: Don't work for updating HTML/class with before print. Only OK for after print (with Chromium 38). See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8a71xxc2/ . Ok with FF (but only with the onbeforeprint function), not with Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Try masking the native `window.print()` with your own...

```
// hide our vars from the global scope
(function(){

  // make a copy of the native window.print
  var _print = this.print;

  // create a new window.print
  this.print = function () {
    // if `onbeforeprint` exists, call it.
    if (this.onbeforeprint) onbeforeprint(this); 
    // call the original `window.print`.
    _print(); 
    // if `onafterprint` exists, call it.
    if (this.onafterprint) onafterprint(this);
  }

}())
```

Updated: comments.

Comment: Thanks @no, but I am having a hard time following your code. You say this will mask the native print function in any browser?  This raises another question for me too, could I just make a JavaScript function that checked EVERY window event and then execute the function I want to execute before printing when `window.print == true`?

Comment: @typoknig: it will; because of that you may want to choose different names for `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint`. I'm assuming you want to catch calls to `window.print` from other scripts besides your own. About the second part of your question, I think it would work, but it sounds like overkill...

Comment: @typoknig: I added code comments to my answer, should help explain what's going on.

Comment: On my page I do not provide the user with a print button, so what I really need to catch is when the user goes to `File > Print` in a non IE browser.  I'll mess around with it a bit and see if I can get your code to work, if not then I might go "overkill" :)

Comment: This won't help you then. Take another look at Wrikken's answer; you can put the data you want into a query string, then add a print css rule that loads an image via a server-side script that stores the data from the query string before responding with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's simply not possible to this properly. Or at least - not with any technology I know nor with any of the answers given previously.

Both using onafterprint and using serverside dynamic-image-generating script would tell you that the page was printed even when the visitor merely went to print preview mode and then canceled out.

However, I would like to learn how to get the proper information, so that I can be *sure* that page was actually printed.