# Can you have call javascript only when print is called?

Tags: javascript, printing

I need to only use a piece of javascript when the print button is clicked, is there a way to do this?

EDIT: A browser print button, i was thinking something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path" media="print"></script>
```

Comment: do you mean the browser print button?

Comment: This appears to make no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a partial support from browsers for that. Consider using special CSS stylesheet for print version of the page. For more details look at this question (there are links to several others): [execute javascript when printing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644628/execute-javascript-when-printing-page/7644833#7644833)

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers (Firefox and IE) have events onBeforePrint onAfterPrint ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Printing#Detecting_print_requests

Failing that use a "Press this to print" button and perform what you want from there ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:
JQuery:

```
$('#btnprint').click(function(){
     //Your JS code goes here
});
```

Watch out with postbacks!

Im not sure wether u mean the browsers print button or just a custom one, the code above is for your own custom one..

Comment: I see what you did there :p