# How I can add JavaScript functions only for the print view

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form which is for the printing purpose. The html form have two different style sheet for the web view and print view. I want to add two different JavaScript functions (those function has using to handle the dynamic height for the row in the form but not working in the print view).

How I can add a JS function only for the print view?.

I am using the following code for the print view. But its not working .

```
@Printing = print : () -> if /TappyNativeApp/.exec(navigator.userAgent) document.location = "toppy:printView:" else if window.print alert("hi") heightvalue = $(".show_seller_box").outerHeight(); $(".buyer_box").outerHeight(heightvalue); window.print() jQuery ($) -> $('.print_btn').click( (event) -> Printing.print() )'
```

Comment: More details please with code sample.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Also the question is unclear. Are you saying that the code that adjusts the height is not running in print view?

Comment: I am using the current code for the print view. But its not working . `@Printing =
  print : () ->
    if /TappyNativeApp/.exec(navigator.userAgent)
      document.location = "toppy:printView:"
    else
      if window.print
        alert("hi")
        heightvalue = $(".show_seller_box").outerHeight();
        $(".buyer_box").outerHeight(heightvalue);
        window.print()

jQuery ($) ->
  $('.print_btn').click(
    (event) ->
      Printing.print()
  )'`

Comment: hmm something is not right here.

Comment: Does this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726252/can-you-have-call-javascript-only-when-print-is-called help you?

Comment: I have tried this. Unfortunately it is not working. If there are any other way ?.