# How do I print a page using javascript and hide headers?

Tags: javascript, html, extends

I have a page on my website called printUsers.html.
On it there is a button which prints the page using 'javascript:window.print()'.
I am also using '@media print' on the page to hide some buttons when the page is printed.
This is all working well and I have no problems here.

The problem is the following:
All the pages on the site, extend from the main page. So at the top of printUsers.html I have:
`#{extends 'App/main.html' /}`

This includes styles and a header which has buttons and drop-downs.
When the user clicks the print button, I want to hide all the header and buttons etc, which come from the main.html.
I tried wrapping it into a div, giving it an id and hiding it but this didn't work.

I have just started using javascript so any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `display:none;` to whatever elements you want hidden in your print @media print CSS?
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7644857/1451422

Comment: yep. That's what i'm doing for certain buttons which are wrapped in divs.
But I couldn't understand how to hide elements (like a header) which extends from a different page i.e main.html.

Comment: Even when they are extended, they are supposed to be "loaded" inside the actual page. so if you want to hide to `header` element, take a look at my answer (I edited it).

Comment: excellent. Didn't realise that I could add elements into my media.print which were extended.
I gave the header an Id and it does just what I want. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The CSS way

### @media print

Use `@media Print` as you stated in your question, but include all the elements you don't want to see in your printed result, and put `display:none` to them. You can also apply some `margin:0 auto; text-align:center;` to your main content if you want to center it into your page.

**Edit:** You can hide any element, such as `header` this way:

```
header
{
    display:none;
}

footer
{
    display:none;
}
```

---

## The Javascript way

### Button's onClick

Your button's onclick:

**Button onClick()**

```
<button id="printThatText" name="printThatText" onclick="printPage();">Print this page</button>"
```

Your javascript code in the header (or at the end of the page)

**Javascript**

```
function printPage()
{
    var myDropDown = document.getElementById('myDropDown');
    myDropDown.style.display = "none";
    //Whatever other elements to hide.
    window.print();
    myDropDown.style.display = "block";
    return true;
}
```

---

You could also put all of these elements in an array and make a `for ... in ...` loop to show/hide them.

Comment: I'm currently using display:none within my media print, in order to hide buttons. The buttons were easy because I just put them in a div, and add the div id to my @media print (just as you said).
However, the header extends from a different html page so this is what confuses me as I can't wrap the text : #{extends 'Application/main.html' /}, inside a div? Did you mean that I should add the id of the header (which is in main.html) to my media Print?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the contents with an element that encapsulates all of stuff you want to hide. In the print CSS, set the display to none.

**The CSS:**

```
@media print {
    #myHeader, #myFooter { display: none }
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="myHeader">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>My link</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="myContent">
  <p>This will print fine</p>
</div>
<div id="myFooter">
  <p>This will not print</p>
</div>
```

You could always use HTML5 header/footer elements!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the opposite--print only a particular div--rather than hiding other divs: [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)