# Invoke cordova specific views once logged in

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am new to mobile development.
I have a web app for which I now need mobile app. I am using Cordova for it. 
The problem is once I have logged in I want to have different views for web/ mobile user. How do I redirect of cordova specific views once logged in? 
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to add a sort of authentication that will enable you to render a specific view based on a user's current state. Say login view if they are not logged in and then probably the dashboard if they've previously logged in. Am I correct?

Comment: I have user authentication in place. When mobile app is started it is reirected to web target :   var targetUrl = "http://localhost:XXXX/"; Which takes care of login. My problem is once logged in want web user and mbile user to have different view. HOw do I do this? Or should I not redirect to web in first place and have new login for mobile, but would not that defeat one codebase purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41432618/8852554),

I think it can help you with what you are looking for