# How to hide a Javascript only on Chrome for smartphone? But not in other mobile browsers (or) desktop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, smartphone

I have an inline javascript on my webpage which I don't want to be downloaded nor parsed nor executed for Chrome on smartphones.

How can this be achieved? I want this because the script's function is useless on Chrome on the smartphones. It just makes the webpage slow since the javascript has to be downloaded, parsed and executed.

The script is already in the footer, but still, it's better to just hide it on smartphone Chrome.

Thanks in advance.

This is my script

```js
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">
eval(function(e,t,n,o,i,a){if(i=function(e){return(t>e?"":i(parseInt(e/t)))+((e%=t)>35?String.fromCharCode(e+29):e.toString(36))},!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;n--;)a[i(n)]=o[n]||i(n)
o=[function(e){return a[e]}],i=function(){return"\\w+"},n=1}for(;n--;)o[n]&&(e=e.replace(RegExp("\\b"+i(n)+"\\b","g"),o[n]))
return e}(";q O='',28='1V';1R(q i=0;i<12;i++)O+=28.X(D.N(D.J()*28.F));q 2A=8,2u=4q,2w=4p,2y=55,2U=B(t){q o=!1,i=B(){z(k.1g){k.2T('2Z',e);E.2T('1U',e)}P{k.2P('2O',e);E.2P('1W',e)}},e=B(){z(!o&&(k.1g||4o.2d==='1U'||k.2J==='37')){o=!0;i();t()}};z(k.2J==='37'){t()}P z(k.1g){k.1g('2Z',e);E.1g('1U',e)}P{k.2M('2O',e);E.2M('1W',e);q n=!1;2K{n=E.4m==4l&&k.1Y}2Q(a){};z(n&&n.2L){(B r(){z(o)G;2K{n.2L('17')}2Q(e){G 4k(r,50)};o=!0;i();t()})()}}};E[''+O+'']=(B(){q t={t$:'1V+/=',4j:B(e){q r='',d,n,o,c,s,l,i,a=0;e=t.e$(e);1a(a<e.F){d=e.14(a++);n=e.14(a++);o=e.14(a++);c=d>>2;s=(d&3)<<4|n>>4;l=(n&15)<<2|o>>6;i=o&63;z(2V(n)){l=i=64}P z(2V(o)){i=64};r=r+U.t$.X(c)+U.t$.X(s)+U.t$.X(l)+U.t$.X(i)};G r},11:B(e){q n='',d,l,c,s,a,i,r,o=0;e=e.1A(/[^A-4i-4h-9\\+\\/\\=]/g,'');1a(o<e.F){s=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));a=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));i=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));r=U.t$.1H(e.X(o++));d=s<<2|a>>4;l=(a&15)<<4|i>>2;c=(i&3)<<6|r;n=n+S.T(d);z(i!=64){n=n+S.T(l)};z(r!=64){n=n+S.T(c)}};n=t.n$(n);G n},e$:B(t){t=t.1A(/;/g,';');q n='';1R(q o=0;o<t.F;o++){q e=t.14(o);z(e<1s){n+=S.T(e)}P z(e>4g&&e<4f){n+=S.T(e>>6|4e);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}P{n+=S.T(e>>12|2p);n+=S.T(e>>6&63|1s);n+=S.T(e&63|1s)}};G n},n$:B(t){q o='',e=0,n=4d=1u=0;1a(e<t.F){n=t.14(e);z(n<1s){o+=S.T(n);e++}P z(n>4b&&n<2p){1u=t.14(e+1);o+=S.T((n&31)<<6|1u&63);e+=2}P{1u=t.14(e+1);2m=t.14(e+2);o+=S.T((n&15)<<12|(1u&63)<<6|2m&63);e+=3}};G o}};q r=['3W==','4a','49=','48','47','46=','45=','44=','43','42','41=','40=','3Z','3Y','3X=','4r','4c=','4s=','4K=','4M=','4N=','4O=','4P==','4Q==','4R==','4L==','4S=','4U','4V','4W','4X','4Y','4Z','4T==','4J=','4u=','3U=','4H==','4G=','4F','4E=','4D=','4C==','4B=','4A==','4z==','4y=','4x=','4w','4v==','4t==','3V','3C==','3o='],y=D.N(D.J()*r.F),Y=t.11(r[y]),w=Y,Q=1,W='#3m',a='#3l',v='#3k',g='#3j',Z='',p='3h!',b='3g 3e 3c 3a\\'38 39 3b 2f 2g. 3p\\'s 3i.  3r 3G\\'t?',u='3S 3R 3Q-3P, 3O 3q\\'t 3M 3L U 3J 3H.',s='I 3F, I 3s 3E 3D 2f 2g.  3z 3y 3w!',o=0,f=0,n='3v.3u',l=0,C=e()+'.2k';B h(t){z(t)t=t.1S(t.F-15);q o=k.2F('2x');1R(q n=o.F;n--;){q e=S(o[n].1G);z(e)e=e.1S(e.F-15);z(e===t)G!0};G!1};B m(t){z(t)t=t.1S(t.F-15);q e=k.3d;x=0;1a(x<e.F){1n=e[x].1Q;z(1n)1n=1n.1S(1n.F-15);z(1n===t)G!0;x++};G!1};B e(t){q n='',o='1V';t=t||30;1R(q e=0;e<t;e++)n+=o.X(D.N(D.J()*o.F));G n};B i(o){q i=['3x','3A==','3B','3I','2Y','3K==','3N=','3f==','3n=','51==','4I==','53==','5k','6r','6u','2Y'],a=['33=','6s==','6t==','6w==','6y=','6e','6o=','67=','33=','6d','52==','6i','6m==','6n==','66==','6q='];x=0;1P=[];1a(x<o){c=i[D.N(D.J()*i.F)];d=a[D.N(D.J()*a.F)];c=t.11(c);d=t.11(d);q r=D.N(D.J()*2)+1;z(r==1){n='//'+c+'/'+d}P{n='//'+c+'/'+e(D.N(D.J()*20)+4)+'.2k'};1P[x]=26 24();1P[x].1X=B(){q t=1;1a(t<7){t++}};1P[x].1G=n;x++}};B L(t){};G{35:B(t,a){z(6l k.K=='6k'){G};q o='0.1',a=w,e=k.1d('1y');e.1k=a;e.j.1h='1O';e.j.17='-1o';e.j.V='-1o';e.j.1t='2c';e.j.13='6j';q d=k.K.2e,r=D.N(d.F/2);z(r>15){q n=k.1d('29');n.j.1h='1O';n.j.1t='1r';n.j.13='1r';n.j.V='-1o';n.j.17='-1o';k.K.5Z(n,k.K.2e[r]);n.1f(e);q i=k.1d('1y');i.1k='2q';i.j.1h='1O';i.j.17='-1o';i.j.V='-1o';k.K.1f(i)}P{e.1k='2q';k.K.1f(e)};l=6f(B(){z(e){t((e.1T==0),o);t((e.23==0),o);t((e.1K=='2G'),o);t((e.1N=='2n'),o);t((e.1J==0),o)}P{t(!0,o)}},27)},1F:B(e,c){z((e)&&(o==0)){o=1;E[''+O+''].1z();E[''+O+''].1F=B(){G}}P{q u=t.11('61'),f=k.6c(u);z((f)&&(o==0)){z((2u%3)==0){q l='6b=';l=t.11(l);z(h(l)){z(f.1E.1A(/\\s/g,'').F==0){o=1;E[''+O+''].1z()}}}};q y=!1;z(o==0){z((2w%3)==0){z(!E[''+O+''].2z){q d=['6a==','69==','68=','6p=','62='],m=d.F,a=d[D.N(D.J()*m)],r=a;1a(a==r){r=d[D.N(D.J()*m)]};a=t.11(a);r=t.11(r);i(D.N(D.J()*2)+1);q n=26 24(),s=26 24();n.1X=B(){i(D.N(D.J()*2)+1);s.1G=r;i(D.N(D.J()*2)+1)};s.1X=B(){o=1;i(D.N(D.J()*3)+1);E[''+O+''].1z()};n.1G=a;z((2y%3)==0){n.1W=B(){z((n.13<8)&&(n.13>0)){E[''+O+''].1z()}}};i(D.N(D.J()*3)+1);E[''+O+''].2z=!0};E[''+O+''].1F=B(){G}}}}},1z:B(){z(f==1){q M=2C.3T('2D');z(M>0){G!0}P{2C.6v('2D',(D.J()+1)*27)}};q h='6C==';h=t.11(h);z(!m(h)){q c=k.1d('5w');c.1Z('5X','5t');c.1Z('2d','1m/5s');c.1Z('1Q',h);k.2F('5r')[0].1f(c)};5q(l);k.K.1E='';k.K.j.16+='R:1r !19';k.K.j.16+='1C:1r !19';q C=k.1Y.23||E.34||k.K.23,y=E.5p||k.K.1T||k.1Y.1T,r=k.1d('1y'),Q=e();r.1k=Q;r.j.1h='2l';r.j.17='0';r.j.V='0';r.j.13=C+'1v';r.j.1t=y+'1v';r.j.2H=W;r.j.21='5o';k.K.1f(r);q d='<a 1Q=\"5n://5m.5l\" j=\"H-1e:10.5Y;H-1j:1i-1l;1c:5j;\">5h 54 5g 2x</a>';d=d.1A('5f',e());d=d.1A('5e',e());q i=k.1d('1y');i.1E=d;i.j.1h='1O';i.j.1B='1I';i.j.17='1I';i.j.13='5d';i.j.1t='5c';i.j.21='2i';i.j.1J='.6';i.j.2j='2h';i.1g('5a',B(){n=n.59('').58().57('');E.2E.1Q='//'+n});k.1D(Q).1f(i);q o=k.1d('1y'),L=e();o.1k=L;o.j.1h='2l';o.j.V=y/7+'1v';o.j.5u=C-5i+'1v';o.j.5v=y/3.5+'1v';o.j.2H='#5K';o.j.21='2i';o.j.16+='H-1j: \"5W 5V\", 1w, 1x, 1i-1l !19';o.j.16+='5U-1t: 5T !19';o.j.16+='H-1e: 5S !19';o.j.16+='1m-1p: 1q !19';o.j.16+='1C: 5R !19';o.j.1K+='2R';o.j.2S='1I';o.j.5Q='1I';o.j.5O='2v';k.K.1f(o);o.j.5N='1r 5L 5J -5x 5I(0,0,0,0.3)';o.j.1N='36';q w=30,Y=22,x=18,Z=18;z((E.34<32)||(5H.13<32)){o.j.2N='50%';o.j.16+='H-1e: 5F !19';o.j.2S='5E;';i.j.2N='65%';q w=22,Y=18,x=12,Z=12};o.1E='<2X j=\"1c:#5D;H-1e:'+w+'1L;1c:'+a+';H-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;H-1M:5C;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;\">'+p+'</2X><2I j=\"H-1e:'+Y+'1L;H-1M:5B;H-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;1c:'+a+';R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;1m-1p:1q;\">'+b+'</2I><5A j=\" 1K: 2R;R-V: 0.2W;R-1B: 0.2W;R-17: 2a;R-2B: 2a; 2r:5z 5y #6g; 13: 25%;1m-1p:1q;\"><p j=\"H-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l;H-1M:2s;H-1e:'+x+'1L;1c:'+a+';1m-1p:1q;\">'+u+'</p><p j=\"R-V:5G;\"><29 5M=\"U.j.1J=.9;\" 5P=\"U.j.1J=1;\"  1k=\"'+e()+'\" j=\"2j:2h;H-1e:'+Z+'1L;H-1j:1w, 1x, 1i-1l; H-1M:2s;2r-56:2v;1C:1b;5b-1c:'+v+';1c:'+g+';1C-17:2c;1C-2B:2c;13:60%;R:2a;R-V:1b;R-1B:1b;\" 6h=\"E.2E.6B();\">'+s+'</29></p>'}}})();E.2t=B(t,e){q n=6x.6z,o=E.6A,r=n(),i,a=B(){n()-r<e?i||o(a):t()};o(a);G{3t:B(){i=1}}};q 2o;z(k.K){k.K.j.1N='36'};2U(B(){z(k.1D('2b')){k.1D('2b').j.1N='2G';k.1D('2b').j.1K='2n'};2o=E.2t(B(){E[''+O+''].35(E[''+O+''].1F,E[''+O+''].4n)},2A*27)});",62,411,"|||||||||||||||||||style|document||||||var|||||||||if||function||Math|window|length|return|font||random|body|||floor|bGCzfNwfynis|else||margin|String|fromCharCode|this|top||charAt||||decode||width|charCodeAt||cssText|left||important|while|10px|color|createElement|size|appendChild|addEventListener|position|sans|family|id|serif|text|thisurl|5000px|align|center|0px|128|height|c2|px|Helvetica|geneva|DIV|HBbjbgWxmv|replace|bottom|padding|getElementById|innerHTML|dgbJnyIUWi|src|indexOf|30px|opacity|display|pt|weight|visibility|absolute|spimg|href|for|substr|clientHeight|load|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|onload|onerror|documentElement|setAttribute||zIndex||clientWidth|Image||new|1000|eVMoZjgdJr|div|auto|babasbmsgx|60px|type|childNodes|ad|blocker|pointer|10000|cursor|jpg|fixed|c3|none|hOujjKPVHh|224|banner_ad|border|300|VIlGZYsxJB|yqNKWNJpks|15px|QsglBqWqmD|script|ymwazBHksb|ranAlready|pDKqNLxKiK|right|sessionStorage|babn|location|getElementsByTagName|hidden|backgroundColor|h1|readyState|try|doScroll|attachEvent|zoom|onreadystatechange|detachEvent|catch|block|marginLeft|removeEventListener|lvlneyLNtH|isNaN|5em|h3|cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t|DOMContentLoaded|||640|ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|innerWidth|aSCmfHLQue|visible|complete|re|using|you|an|like|styleSheets|looks|YWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuYW9sLmNvbQ|It|Welcome|okay|FFFFFF|adb8ff|777777|EEEEEE|Y2FzLmNsaWNrYWJpbGl0eS5jb20|c3BvbnNvcmVkX2xpbms|That|can|Who|have|clear|kcolbdakcolb|moc|in|YWRuLmViYXkuY29t|me|Let|YWQubWFpbC5ydQ|anVpY3lhZHMuY29t|b3V0YnJhaW4tcGFpZA|my|disabled|understand|doesn|awesome|YWQuZm94bmV0d29ya3MuY29t|site|YS5saXZlc3BvcnRtZWRpYS5ldQ|making|keep|YWdvZGEubmV0L2Jhbm5lcnM|we|income|advertising|without|But|getItem|QWRDb250YWluZXI|Z29vZ2xlX2Fk|YWQtbGVmdA|QWQ3Mjh4OTA|QWQzMDB4MjUw|QWQzMDB4MTQ1|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTI|YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTE|YWQtY29udGFpbmVy|YWQtZm9vdGVy|YWQtbGI|YWQtbGFiZWw|YWQtaW5uZXI|YWQtaW1n|YWQtaGVhZGVy|YWQtZnJhbWU|YWRCYW5uZXJXcmFw|191|QWRGcmFtZTE|c1|192|2048|127|z0|Za|encode|setTimeout|null|frameElement|fTbvqGLWre|event|232|166|QWRBcmVh|QWRGcmFtZTI|YWRzZW5zZQ|QWRCb3gxNjA|cG9wdXBhZA|YWRzbG90|YmFubmVyaWQ|YWRzZXJ2ZXI|YWRfY2hhbm5lbA|IGFkX2JveA|YmFubmVyYWQ|YWRBZA|YWRiYW5uZXI|YWRCYW5uZXI|YmFubmVyX2Fk|YWRUZWFzZXI|Z2xpbmtzd3JhcHBlcg|YWRzLnlhaG9vLmNvbQ|QWREaXY|QWRGcmFtZTM|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wNA|QWRGcmFtZTQ|QWRMYXllcjE|QWRMYXllcjI|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMQ|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMg|QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMw|RGl2QWQ|QWRJbWFnZQ|RGl2QWQx|RGl2QWQy|RGl2QWQz|RGl2QWRB|RGl2QWRC|RGl2QWRD||cHJvbW90ZS5wYWlyLmNvbQ|c3F1YXJlLWFkLnBuZw|YWRzLnp5bmdhLmNvbQ|adblock||radius|join|reverse|split|click|background|40px|160px|FILLVECTID2|FILLVECTID1|detection|quick|120|black|YWRzYXR0LmFiY25ld3Muc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|com|blockadblock|http|9999|innerHeight|clearInterval|head|css|stylesheet|minWidth|minHeight|link|8px|solid|1px|hr|500|200|999|45px|18pt|35px|screen|rgba|24px|fff|14px|onmouseover|boxShadow|borderRadius|onmouseout|marginRight|12px|16pt|normal|line|Black|Arial|rel|5pt|insertBefore||aW5zLmFkc2J5Z29vZ2xl|Ly93d3cuZG91YmxlY2xpY2tieWdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28||||d2lkZV9za3lzY3JhcGVyLmpwZw|Q0ROLTMzNC0xMDktMTM3eC1hZC1iYW5uZXI|Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZy55YWhvby5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vYWR4L2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLmljbw|Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9hZHNlbnNlL3N0YXJ0L2ltYWdlcy9mYXZpY29uLmljbw|Ly9wYWdlYWQyLmdvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbS9wYWdlYWQvanMvYWRzYnlnb29nbGUuanM|querySelector|YWQtbGFyZ2UucG5n|MTM2N19hZC1jbGllbnRJRDI0NjQuanBn|setInterval|CCC|onclick|ZmF2aWNvbjEuaWNv|468px|undefined|typeof|YmFubmVyX2FkLmdpZg|bGFyZ2VfYmFubmVyLmdpZg|YWRjbGllbnQtMDAyMTQ3LWhvc3QxLWJhbm5lci1hZC5qcGc|Ly9hZHMudHdpdHRlci5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28|YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudC0zNDMyMy5qcGc|YWRzYXR0LmVzcG4uc3RhcndhdmUuY29t|YmFubmVyLmpwZw|NDY4eDYwLmpwZw|YXMuaW5ib3guY29t|setItem|NzIweDkwLmpwZw|Date|c2t5c2NyYXBlci5qcGc|now|requestAnimationFrame|reload|Ly95dWkueWFob29hcGlzLmNvbS8zLjE4LjEvYnVpbGQvY3NzcmVzZXQvY3NzcmVzZXQtbWluLmNzcw".split("|"),0,{}))
</script>
```

Comment: so detect browser/device/size and append the script to the page

Comment: `if (!(thisIsAnEnvironmentWhereItsGonnaBeSlowAndUseless())) { /* code */ }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect between a Desktop and Mobile Chrome User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393865/how-do-you-detect-between-a-desktop-and-mobile-chrome-user-agent)

Comment: Could someone please provide me the actual full code. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321709/how-to-handle-what-does-this-malicious-obfuscated-code-do-questions

Comment: @M.K.Dan That's not how this website works; *you* are supposed to do all the work.

Comment: $.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); if($.browser.chrome){ HELLO WORLD. THIS IS CHROME }

Comment: The above code works with earlier versions of JQuery. How can I modify it to detect if the browser is not equal to Chrome mobile? And can I simply replace the text message with my script?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for User Agent, the one from Chrome Mobile is:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"
 [source](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings)

you can access it from `navigator.userAgent` and then append the script code to the page only if it isn't Chrome Mobile

**EDIT**

I would try simply with:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/i)
 && navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobile/i)){
     // append the script
 }
```

Comment: $.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

if($.browser.chrome){
  HELLO WORLD. THIS IS CHROME

}

Comment: The above code works with earlier versions of JQuery. How can I modify it to detect if the browser is not equal to Chrome mobile? And can I simply replace the text message with my script?

Comment: No need to use JQuery, it's a lot easier with vanilla javascript