# How to change template in Angular dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to substitute differ template if user comes from mobile device and another template if it is web.

How to change template in Angular dynamically?

I reviewed a few the same questions here, but they are about Angular JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `ng-template` for this. Would look something like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isWeb(); else mobileTemplate">
...
</ng-container>
<ng-template #mobileTemplate>
...
</ng-template>
```

For the `isWeb()` implementation I would use `navigator.userAgent`, see [How do you detect between a Desktop and Mobile Chrome User Agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393865/how-do-you-detect-between-a-desktop-and-mobile-chrome-user-agent/25394023#25394023)

this way it will display the content in the `ng-template` when you are on mobile and the content in the `ng-container` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngTemplateOutlet` to do this:

In your HTML:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate">

</ng-container>

<div>
  <button (click)="changeTemplate()"> Change Template </button>
</div>


<ng-template #webTemplate>
   <h3> Hey, I'm web template</h3>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #mobileTemplate>
  <h3> Hey, I'm mobile template</h3>
</ng-template>
```

In your component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('mobileTemplate') mobileTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('webTemplate') webTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  web: boolean;
  name = 'Dynamic Temmplates';
  constructor() {
    this.web = true;
  }
  get getTemplate() {
    if (this.web) {
      return this.webTemplate;
    }
    else {
      return this.mobileTemplate;
    }

  }

  changeTemplate() {
    this.web = !this.web;
  }
}
```

You can find the **stackblitz** demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apnrs5)

More on `NgTemplateOutlet` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)