# After click print button page redirected to another page javascript

Tags: javascript, php

After clicking the print button, page should automatically redirect to another page. I attached the screenshot and code below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esYfY.jpg)

**javascript**

```
<script>
        myFunction();

        function myFunction()
        {

                window.print();
             //  setTimeout(closePrintView(), 3000);
        }
            function closePrintView() {
                window.location.href = 'purchase3.php';
            }

    </script>
```

in this code before printing  page redirected

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I think put `window.location.href = 'purchase3.php';` before `window.print()`

Comment: Can you let us know why do you want to redirect to another page? Showing them a PDF using `Content-Disposition:inline` should be enough.

Comment: i am developing pos system. after complete, the sales form page redirect to print page after click print form. page redirect  sales form again.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish). It may help you to achieve what you're trying to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.onafterprint` to fire other script codes after it is printed.

```js
window.onafterprint = function(e){
    closePrintView();
};

function myFunction(){
    window.print();
}

function closePrintView() {
    window.location.href = 'https://bing.com';   
}
```

```html
<button onClick="myFunction()">Print</button>
```

Comment: You can remove the jquery. It isn't needed.