# how to show loading GIF image or "please wait" message before printing large PDF file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on an "Online Medical report download" website, i have a button called "Download" on page, when click it will redirect to 'report.php' page, end of the body I'm  using `window.print()` method of JavaScript for printing.

its working fine for me, but if I have to download a large file, then print preview takes time to load the page.

I want to show a loading GIF image or Some message if there is a waiting time till file load for printing. so my users can get interaction.

I have tried to search a lot but not found any specific solution for this.

Comment: is the file you serve is fetched through some Ajax call ?

Comment: You can use the approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish . Wherein you can show your loading icon before print event and hide it after print event.

Comment: You could capture the onload event for all the images used, and show progress at same time.

Comment: @AravindAnil no it's not ajax call, on download button click I'm redirecting to second page, end of body I'm calling window.print method

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `onafterprint` and `onbeforeprint` event to do this

```
window.onbeforeprint = function(){
    $('loader').show();
}
window.onafterprint = function() {
    $('loader').hide();
}
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Answer (score 0):

If the page you want to print is dependent on an API call then you might handle the situation with a loader, if it doesn't then you might have to fake it with a setTimeOut function and time which you need to mention in the callback function should be equal to thee time taken by your page to load.

Comment: I know about this function but problem is How i will know the time taken by my page to load so I can pass to the function.