# How get print or cancel button status on browser print dialog (window.print)?

Tags: javascript

I have project that require save something to database after click print button on browser print dialog (window.print).

I have try `onafterprint` based on [How to detect window.print() finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish)
but when i click cancel or close it still save to database.

any idea how to save to database only on click print button ?

Comment: There isn't any way to do this.

Comment: The `window.print()` method launches the print preview window which will not inform back whether the print was successful or cancelled. So you cannot do that.

Comment: Looks like neither `beforeprint` nor `afterprint` tells you whether the user printed, cancelled or if the print was unsuccessful. You will have to find a workaround.