# window.afterprint event not working when calling print() function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using chrome version 109.0.5414.75 and developping an extension.
And when I call print() method to save a page as pdf file, I can't catch afterprint event.
But when I type Ctrl+P commnad then the event fired and after this, print() method fire afterprint event normaly.

The code is in content.js of developping extension.

> The code is very simple in content.js

```
window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {console.log('After printing'); });
```

> When I save as pdf by print() from console of developer tool, the event not fired. but by Ctrl+P if fired.

This situation happens an environment but on other systems no problem(fire the event).
Does someone have some ideas to solve this?

I can use eventdispatch to deal with it, but I want the timing that saved pdf(afterpring).

Comment: Dou you mean "user save as pdf" as Ctrl+P and save as pdf ? I tried and got feedback(afterprint). But print() was not.

Comment: The code is very simple in content.js `window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {console.log('After printing'); });` 
When I save as pdf by print() from console of developer tool, the event not fired. but by Ctrl+P if fired.

Comment: I found a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325025/how-to-detect-window-print-finish. Using window.matchMedia works. But I don't know why afterprint event does not works on my env.

Comment: I'm using chrome version 109.0.5414.87 and have the same problem as you. Then I download Chrome Canary with version 112.0.5569.2, and it works. So I think maybe it's the issue of Chrome?