# Why would window.print() and then window.close() called using register Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() method not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I am trying to call the below method in `Page_Load` of an asp.net page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "print", "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">window.print();window.close();</script>");
```

(or `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method).

This would give a message to close the page in IE (or even close without any message when called as a popup) but works well with Firefox.
Surprisingly, the same events inside a function, when called `onload` of body will work well.

I can use workarounds to get this work but I was wondering why there is a different behaviour here? Does anybody know?

This is the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 
</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
    <div>
        This is a test page!
    </div>
    
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.print();window.close();</script></form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck. This looks like a browser bug due to the fact that you can't print the page until it is fully loaded.  As you saw, this causes the window.close to not work as intended.

Comment: @Hexxagonal I am sorry, the code I pasted before was when I call RegisterClientScriptBlock method. The one now is when I use RegisterStartupScript method. Though it's just moving the script tag up and down the main div inside the form.

Comment: Doesn't window.print gives a print dialog?  You can't close the window until that dialog is done.

Comment: @JasonDam In Firefox, it does. In IE, it doesn't. That's what the issue was, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.print();
  window.onfocus = function () {
     window.close();
  }
</script>
```

From: [Close window automatically after printing dialog closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes)