# Window.print doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, document

I have to print out a `div` which I'm doing in the following way:

```
function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup(elem.html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'to print', 'height=600,width=800');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
```

My problem is that on IE, when I click the button nothing happens. However, on Chrome and Firefox it works. What can I do to print it out correctly?

**EDIT:** I'm call `print` in the following way:

```
$('#print_it').click(function(){
    var element = $('#itinerario');
    PrintElem(element);
});
```

This is where `print_it` is the id of the button.

Another thing I've seen is that after a period of time, Chrome along with other browsers tells me that the page isn't responding. Why is this happening?

Comment: possible dup of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555697/window-print-not-working-in-ie

Comment: couldn't you use `mywindow.document.innerHTML`?

Comment: Where is your click event handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You MUST do a `mywindow.document.close()` and you may **NOT have a space in the window name**

I assume you invoke PrintElem from onclick of something - if that something is a link, you need to return false in the onclick handler!

Here is how I would do it if I had to

```
function PrintElem(elem) { 
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'to_print', 'height=600,width=800');
    var html = '<html><head><title></title>'+
               '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />'+
               '</head><body onload="window.focus(); window.print(); window.close()">'+
               data+
               '</body></html>';
    mywindow.document.write(html);
    mywindow.document.close();
    return true;
}
```

but I am not sure whether or not the window.close() will interfere with the printing

And why not

```
$(function() {
  $('#print_it').click(function(){
    popup($('#itinerario').html());
  });
});
```

Comment: solved... the problem is that i used var mywindow = window.open('', 'a name', 'height=600,width=800'); instead var mywindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'height=600,width=800'); microsoft allows only some argument like name

Comment: I already told you that. No space allowed. My code use underscore

Answer (score 1):

I see you've solved it using mplungjan's note about no spaces in the window name, but an alternative would be to use @media print css styles, crudely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print {
            * {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .printMe {
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                var divToPrint = $("#div3");
                $(divToPrint).addClass("printMe");
                window.print();
                $(divToPrint).removeClass("printMe");
            }
            )
        }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">fhgjghajghhjagjdag</div>
    <div id="div2">ytiyrtiyertuyeyiyt</div>
    <div id="div3">We want to print this one.</div>
    <div id="div4">vnbcxbvmzxbvc,xbv</div>
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use display over visibility since visibility still takes up space on the page

Answer (score 1):

On my case I just needed to use the code below:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was resolved by doing a focus before the print.

window.focus();
window.print();