# window.open New window in compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using the following function to print my my pop up window in Internet Explorer 11:

```
function openWin() {         
     var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
     myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
     myWindow.focus();
     window.print();
}
```

However, `window.print()` only works when the Internet Explorer is opened in compatibility mode. So how can I set the window.open to open the new window in compatibility mode?

EDIT: The answer in the suggested duplicate question didn't work for me I got this error:

> `"You can only have one <title> element within the <head> element."`

The suggested answer that shows the meta tag compatibility mode  doesn't show how to use it in window.open

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window.print doesn't work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782092/window-print-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: CSS Print Media normally makes needing a pop up window for printing not necessary.