# Print the page and close it

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I print the page and close it automatically?

I open a new window/page with button click:

```
protected void ASPxButton_GenerOrd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         string AdrUrl = "Print_Ordo.aspx?SoinId=" + Soin_Id + "&SelId=" + TempId;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", AdrUrl));
    }
```

my Print_Ordo.aspx :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script>         window.print(); window.close();</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <dx:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer_Ordo" runat="server">
        </dx:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my Print_Ordo.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Print_Ordo : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string Soin_ID = "", SelectedID = ""; 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Soin_ID = Request.QueryString["SoinId"];
        SelectedID = Request.QueryString["SelId"];
        //ReportViewer_Ordo.Report = new XtraReport_Ordo(Convert.ToInt32(Soin_ID), SelectedID);
        //ReportViewer_Ordo.PageByPage = false;

        var xtraReport_Pricipal = new XtraReport_Ordo(Convert.ToInt32(Soin_ID), SelectedID);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                PdfExportOptions opts = new PdfExportOptions();
                opts.ShowPrintDialogOnOpen = true;
                xtraReport_Pricipal.ExportToPdf(ms, opts);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                byte[] report = ms.ToArray();
                Page.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Page.Response.Clear();
                Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(report, 0, report.Length);
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            finally
            {
                ms.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The problem is it does not close automaticaly. I tried with:

```
self.close();
window.close();
top.close();
```

None of this works. Any ideas?

PS : as I look at it via Firebug:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://172.18.1.253:4001/source/Print_Ordo.aspx?SoinId=4&amp;SelId=9" type="application/pdf">
```

I think because of this process plugin, I can not close this window.

Comment: Look at console, there shoud be an error "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script". 
This cause you can close windows by JavaScript only was opened by window.open javaScript method.

Comment: Try putting the script in the Body tag.  <body OnLoad='window.print(); window.close();'>  I don't know if that will make any difference, but it's still better than just having the call at the top of the html.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12070246/864989) answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this - Add `Focus` on window before Close

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.print();
    window.onfocus = function() { window.close(); }
</script>
```