# window.close(); after window.print(); javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a js code which will close window right after appearing of pop up print window. Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="print()">Print</a>

function print()
{   
    win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<html><head>blablabla.......');
    win.window.print();
    win.window.close();
}
```

But it doesn't work because window closes before it pop up.

Comment: remove  `win.window.close();`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown closing window..how on earth will this work..you should keep alive window until you print...and dont be abusive and offensive..okay?

Comment: I think you can find what you're looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="print()">Print</a>

    function print()
    {   
        win = window.open();
        win.document.write('<html><head>blablabla.......');

        var document_focus = false; // var we use to monitor document focused status.
        // Now our event handlers.
        $(document).ready(function() { win.window.print();document_focus = true; });
        setInterval(function() { if (document_focus === true) { win.window.close(); }  }, 300);
    }
```

Thanks [Stilltorik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727226/stilltorik) for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes).

Answer (score 2):

In this way, the window will close after print, works perfect!

```
function printme() {         
     var newWindow = window.open();
     newWindow.document.open("text/html");
     newWindow.document.write('<html><head>blablabla.......');
     newWindow.document.close();

     newWindow.print();
     newWindow.onfocus = function () {
        newWindow.close(); // Close the window
     }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me:

```
print = function() {
    var printContents = document.getElementById('div').innerHTML,
      params = [
        'height=' + screen.height,
        'width=' + screen.width,
        'fullscreen=yes'].join(','),

    popup = window.open("", 'popUpWindow', params);
    popup.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" /></head><body class="print" onload="window.print()" onmousemove="setTimeout(function () {window.close()},1000);" >'
      + printContents
      + '</body></html>');
    popup.onfocus = function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        popup.focus();
        popup.document.close();
      }, 200);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet in `JQuery` prints also dynamic images rendered inside the html.

```
  <button id="printreceipt">
  Print
  </button>
  <div id="receipt">
  Colombo was great..
  </div>

$(function(){
$('body').on('click','button#printreceipt',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

var printWindow = window.open('');
var divContents = $("#receipt").html() +
                    "<script>" +
                    "window.onload = function() {" +
                    "     window.print();" +
                    "};" +
                   "setInterval(function() {   {   clearInterval();window.close(); }  }, 300);" +
                    "<" + "/script>";
 printWindow.document.write(divContents);
 printWindow.document.close();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And this was what worked for me (on Chrome):

```
var html = "<html>...</html>";
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(html);
win.document.close();
setTimeout(function () {
   win.focus();
   win.print();
   win.close();
}, 100);
```

The crucial bit was doing the focus() and print() async. Without that I was seeing a blank page in the print preview.