# Open a new page in a new window, print it and closed it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I still can't get this code to work, I am trying to use the "onClick" to swap the image once clicked, open this new page in a new window, print this new opened window and closed it. It opens the new page on the new window, but it prints a blank page and it cant close it, it seems that the focus is not been set somehow. Can any one help me on tis? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Print it</title>
<!--style type="text/css" media="print"> .noprint {visibility: hidden;} </style-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".img-swap").live('click', function() {
if ($(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
} else {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
}
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--

 Popup = {

 init : function () {
 $('a.action_print').bind('click', Popup.printIt);
    },

     printIt : function () {

        var win = window.open('doc1.html','Printed','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250');

        if (win) {
            win.document.close();
             win.focus();
            win.print();
        }

        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Popup.init();
});


 // -->
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <br>
 CLick to Print:<br><br>

<p style=" padding: 125px 0; text-align: center;">
<a class="action_print" target="Printed"><img src="images/cam_off.png" class="img-swap" width="100" height="100" /></a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: No, just running out of options at this point, any suggestions help! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, all works, I just had to make sure that my files I am printing leave in the same domain. I hope it can help others in need for such a thing, but any improvements on the code are welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Open n Print</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
 $(function(){
  function openPrintWindow(url, name, specs) {
    var printWindow = window.open(url, name, specs);
    var printAndClose = function () {
      if (printWindow.document.readyState == 'complete') {
        clearInterval(sched);
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
     }
    }  
      var sched = setInterval(printAndClose, 200);
   };

 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $(".test").on("click", function (e) {

    var myUrl = $(this).attr('data-url');
    alert(myUrl);

    e.preventDefault();
    openPrintWindow(myUrl, "to_print", "width=700,height=400,_blank");
   });
 });

 });//]]>  

  </script>

 </head>
 <body>

  </br>
  <a class="test" href="javascript:;" data-url= "doc.html">open print and close doc</a>
  <br />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printIt` looks weird. At first you close the `document`, then try to print the content. Try this:

```
if (win) {
    win.focus();
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

Closing `document` won't close `window`, hence `win.close()`. Notice also the line order.

Also, jQuery 1.4 is quite old, have you considered to update to a [newer version](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js)?

Comment: I added jQuery newest version "1.11.0" and with that I updated the code to use "on" instead of "live" but it still prints a blank, this is very strange.

Comment: Hmm... But you can see the content within the pop-up? A bullet-proof solution would be to move the function to the `window.onload` handler of the pop-up. Or even better, use [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead of pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You may put your javascript/JQuery code in the place where I put the window.print();

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "UpdateMsg", "window.print();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To let the full content of the window load properly, change the

`printWindow.close()`

to

```
printWindow.onfocus=function(){ printWindow.close();}
```

See [Close window automatically after printing dialog closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes)