# TCPDF Redirect after the print dialog closes

Tags: javascript, php, html, tcpdf

I have an order form which generates a pdf then prints it automatically using TCPDF. 
to print it i have to open it which opens a web PDF.

here is the code that opens my pdf

```
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

how can i redirect the user after the print dialog has closed

Comment: Please post your code to open the PDF. Do you open it in a new window by javascript?

Comment: If it's printed from the web page, look at [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115657/2518525).

Comment: $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');

Comment: try the answers from the page you linked, but replace `window.close();` with `window.location.href='http://target.site'`. If this doesn't work (seems like different browsers behave different) - sorry, don't know

Comment: Might be best to overlay a message on your screen once the print dialog has opened, and try and force the user to "click here to proceed" etc

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("afterprint", af_pri);
function af_pri(){
   window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Comment: You should avoid the code only as an answer rather you should provide a description for the OP as well as for future readers otherwise it can be downvoted or deleted permanently.