# Handle 'Close' event of Print dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [PrintArea](https://plugins.jquery.com/PrintArea/) and I want to handle 'Close' event of Print dialog box(Chrome, Firefox,...). I have tried

```
window.onclose = function(){
   // do something
}
```

but it did not work.

Is there any way to do it?

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes

Comment: @AnthonyAstige It is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.print() //or whatever you want to do
window.onfocus=function(){
//user is back
}
```

Comment: I am using Chrome 51 on Linux

Comment: It triggers only when switch the browser tab. Chrome on windows.

Answer (score 0):

**Do this**

```
window.print() //open the print dialog box
window.onafterprint=function(){
    //do whatever it is you wish to do
}
```

**Note**

This only works for Firefox (>6.0) and Internet Explorer.

For other browsers including Chrome, try `window.matchMedia()`

```
window.print() //open the print dialog box
var printEvent = window.matchMedia('print');
printEvent.addListener(function(printEnd) {
    if (!printEnd.matches) {
        // do whatever you wish to do
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank but it does not work, I am using Chrome 51 on Linux

Comment: No luck. I am using Printarea plugin, uhm uhm.