# Print in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I wrote the below code to print the screen. It is working fine. And it is opening the pdf file also. But behind the pdf file one window is opening. that window will open when we press on pdf file. The problem with that pdf behind window is it is becoming editable. How to remove the behind window.

```
angular.element('#hideLeftLinks').addClass("no-print");
var printContents = angular.element('#Print').html();
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=1000');
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Copyofstyles.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();
popupWin.innerHTML='';  
angular.element('#hideLeftLinks').removeClass("no-print");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes/29329118#29329118). I tested myself and it seems that the answer is the only one working answer for now. I removed `onload="window.print()"` and added `<script>window.print(); setTimeout(window.close, 0);</script>` and it worked. No need for `popupWin.document.close();` and probably `popupWin.innerHTML='';` too. So, replace below three lines

```
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="css/Copyofstyles.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + 
    '</body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();
popupWin.innerHTML='';
```

to

```
popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="css/Copyofstyles.css" /></head><body>' + printContents + 
    '<script>window.print(); setTimeout(window.close, 0);</script></body></html>');
```

Comment: In above code working fine but behind window still opening,could you provide any stuff to close behind window.

Comment: Of course, it's opening. If it does not open, one cannot print the page. The problem is 'the window not closing after pressing Print or Cancel button'.