# How to close the browser pop up window as soon as the print window closes? Looking for code that works on all the browsers

Tags: javascript, safari

The pop up window has the following code to invoke print and it automatically closes the window once the print window closes.

```
<html>
   <body onload="window.focus();window.print();window.close();">
      The content to be printed
   </body>
</html>
```

This code work just fine in most browsers; window.print() blocks the execution of window.close() until the print window is closed either by completing printing or cancelling it. However, the window.print() does not block the execution of window.close() in safari 10.0.1 in mac.

Is there any way to make it work on all the browsers?

Comment: Did you do a search on this? No? Try this "javascript close popup after window print" in google. That gets you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29329118/1819684

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close window automatically after printing dialog closes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes)