# default chrome print function

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, fpdf

[image]

This is the window that appears for printing in browser. This windows appear after opening on a PDF page in a browser. Also this window is next stop after clicking print button in a PDF file generated by FPDF. I am using FPDF and I believe you cant output or add other things aside from your data so [Close window automatically after printing dialog closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460630/close-window-automatically-after-printing-dialog-closes) solution is not valid for my problem. This solution basically add a JS script in the pop up window.

> Is there a way to close this window ***after clicking on the PRINT BUTTON*** for PDF pages. For PDF generated by FPDF?