# Print only when the condition is met not working ( ie 11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, internet-explorer-11

If the user tries to print (using ctrl+p) without checking at least one checkbox on the page an error message gets prompted.   On IE 11,  I do see the error message  but simultaneously the  print window (popup) also appears.  How can I prevent the print window?

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function (event) {

  if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
    switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
      case 'p':
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert('ctrl+p');
        printFunc();
        break;

      }
    }
});
```

Also tried :

```
window.onbeforeprint = function () {
    //alert('ctrl-p');
    printFunc();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};
```

Function:

```
function printFunc() {
    var selectedListinsCount = selected_Listings.join('').split('').length;
    if (selectedListinsCount < 1) {
          if ($('#errmesg').length == 0) {
            $('.messageCenter').append('<span id="errmesg" class ="errmesg"> <span class="messageIcon"></span><span>Please select at least one listing</span></span>');
          }
        $('.messageCenter').show();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('.errmesg').remove();
        $('.messageCenter').hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW, unless you're stuck using an old version of jQuery, use `on` instead of `bind`.

Comment: Perhaps [intercept the event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662720/1576269) rather than the keypress?

Comment: @Owlvark tried window.onbeforeprint but the problem persists.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says "Cancelable: no"

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that inhibiting browsers' OS-level functionality is probably not the best approach, and becoming less possible over time- essentially if you did get this working, it'd be a bit of a hack that would lack sustainability.

Consider changing your flow to incorporate validation BEFORE presenting the data you want the user to print.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return;` instead of `return false;`.