# Run javascript function on browser Print wizard

Tags: javascript, printing, browser

I want to detect if the user click the print or cancel button *in the printing options in the browser for certain pages* (e.g. File -> Print Preview, Print). I like to display a message (separate message if the user click cancel or print).

Here's my code:

```
function printCheckout() {
    (function() {
        if(print){
              ///if print button click
        } else {
              ///cancel button click
          }

    }());

    window.print();
}
```

Comment: See the highest rated answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339789/onbeforeprint-and-onafterprint-equivalent-for-non-ie-browsers

Comment: please research in other questions before ask your own...

Comment: my problem is when i click cancel the same message appear

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own print wizard by *popup* on print event. You can't define javascript events on browser wizards! They can't be run in such case.